# Add metadata to image upload to S3 with Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, png, content-type, boto

I'm successfully adding an image to a bucket on S3, but the problem is I'm not sure how to set the content-type to 'image/png'.  Here is my code

```
image = Image.open(self.image)
conn = S3Connection(settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)     
out_im2 = cStringIO.StringIO()
image.save(out_im2, 'PNG')
b = conn.get_bucket('new_test_bucket')
k = b.new_key(self.title+'.png')
k.set_contents_from_filename(str(self.image))
```

Currently it is being uploaded as 'application/octet-stream'.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is how my image upload code (using boto) works:

```
k.set_metadata('Content-Type', mime)
k.set_contents_from_file(data, policy='public-read')
k.set_acl('public-read')
```

Well at least part of it.

Answer (score 0):

I found that setting the metadata before you `set_contents_from_file` works for me.  I am using GCS though, so maybe that's different..

```
bucket = conn.get_bucket('plots')
k = bucket.new_key('000006')
k.set_metadata('Content-Type', 'image/png')
k.set_contents_from_stream(buff)
```